# Does Rollback automatically end transaction in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Using PostgreSQL 9.1

In this code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    // Do something
If error then
    ROLLBACK  //<--Does this automatically End Transaction
Else
    COMMIT  //<--Automatically Ends Transaction
End if
```

Is an END TRANSACTION command necessary after the ROLLBACK command?

Comment: Is this pseudo code? Please give us some context. (It seems PL/pgSQL, but you cannot use explicit transactions in it & if/then/else is not supported in plain SQL)

Comment: You can close a transaction with commit or rollback.
END is a PostgreSQL extension that provides functionality equivalent to COMMIT, which is specified in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rollback` has end Your transaction, no need another command.

Here some example :

```
test_general=# begin;
BEGIN
test_general=# lock TABLE t1 ;
LOCK TABLE
test_general=# select locktype, relname, mode from pg_locks l inner join pg_class c on c.oid = l.relation;
 locktype |          relname           |        mode         
----------+----------------------------+---------------------
 relation | pg_namespace_oid_index     | AccessShareLock
 relation | pg_class_relname_nsp_index | AccessShareLock
 relation | t1                         | AccessExclusiveLock
test_general=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
test_general=# select locktype, relname, mode from pg_locks l inner join pg_class c on c.oid = l.relation;
 locktype |          relname           |      mode       
----------+----------------------------+-----------------
 relation | pg_class_relname_nsp_index | AccessShareLock
 relation | pg_class_oid_index         | AccessShareLock
 relation | pg_class                   | AccessShareLock
 relation | pg_locks                   | AccessShareLock
(4 rows)
```

Lock released means that the transaction is over.